# Symfony 3 separated external form event listener

Tags: forms, symfony, listener, addeventlistener

I have a form type

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/ProductType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('price');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

I want to add fields to this type using [FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#a-the-formevents-pre-set-data-event)

I know i can add it inside the ProductType

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            // ... adding the new field
        });
```

But i don't have the privileges to edit in the original form type because it is included in a vendor package.

How to add this field in a separated listener "FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA" event in this form without editing the original form type file and without overriding it?

Comment: Couldn't you just extend the class and make your own modifications there?

Comment: This will require to change contents in controller & route also to refer to the new form class.

Comment: Right - what's the problem with doing that?

Comment: I will do it in this way if i don't find another solution to use an external listener.
Thank you

Comment: depending on if the vendor did a good job, they may have defined a parameter pointing to this formtype, allowing you to easely overwrite this param, to point to your own formtype, without having to touch the vendor code